# error[E0308]: mismatched types expected `()`, found `bool`. How to remove this error?

Tags: types, rust, return, boolean, palindrome

**program to check palindrome**

```
pub fn is_palindrome(str: &str, start: i32, end: i32) -> bool

{

    //if empty string
    if str.is_empty() {
        true
    }

    // If there is only one character
    if start == end {
        true
    }

    // If first and last
    // characters do not match
    if str.chars().nth(start as usize) != str.chars().nth(end as usize) {
        false
    }

    // If there are more than
    // two characters, check if
    // middle substring is also
    // palindrome or not.
    if start < end + 1 {
        is_palindrome(str, start + 1, end - 1)
    }
    true
}
```

This is my code I get error in return statements.
It says
error[E0308]: mismatched types
expected `()`, found `bool`
Please tell how to solve this.

Comment: "I get error in return statements" - what return statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget the [return statements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/return-expr.html) which has to be used if you want to return a value earlier from within a function (See also [Functions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/fn.html)):

```rust
pub fn is_palindrome(str: &str, start: i32, end: i32) -> bool {

    //if empty string
    if str.is_empty() {
        return true;
    }

    // If there is only one character
    if start == end {
        return true;
    }

    // If first and last
    // characters do not match
    if str.chars().nth(start as usize) != str.chars().nth(end as usize) {
        return false;
    }

    // If there are more than
    // two characters, check if
    // middle substring is also
    // palindrome or not.
    if start < end + 1 {
        return is_palindrome(str, start + 1, end - 1);
    }
    true
}
```